# Is it a good practice to use 'createModel' in REST?

Tags: rest, api, restful-url

I'm looking for a best way for implementing an endpoint of REST-full application that will be responsible for creating a new library orders. Let's assume that I have the following resources. 
[image]

If I want to get all books of a particular author I can use the next endpoint:

```
HTTP GET
api/books/author/123
```

If I want to fetch all orders of a particular book I can use the endpoint provided below:

```
HTTP GET
api/books/456/orders
```

My question is what will be the most suitable URL and a request model for an endpoint that will create orders? 
From my perspective it can be

```
HTTP POST
api/books/456/orders
```

And one more question. Is it a good practice in REST to use request models like `CreateOrder`? If I want to create a REST-full web application can I use the following request model:

```
class CreateOrder 
{
   AuthorId: number;
   BookId: number;
   ClientId: number;
}
```

Sometimes it makes me confused. Should request models look like our resources or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your end-point does not need to always start with `/books`. You can introduce another end-point `/orders` for creating or getting orders. So , to create an order , you can :

```
HTTP POST
api/orders
```

And does the 'request model' that you mean is the HTTP request body structure ? If yes, it does not need to be 100% match with your back-end persisted/domain model. Just include enough parameters that the server needs to know in order to create an order. (e.g. Include bookId rather than the whole book object etc.)

BTW , to get all books for a particular author , it is more common to use query parameter such as :

```
HTTP GET
api/books?authorId=123
```

Comment: Let me ask 2 short questions ;)
1) Can I use any request model that I want? Will it satisfy REST-full application criteria? 
2) Will these 2 URL be valid in terms of REST? Perhaps the second endpoint is better, but I am interested in following REST style.
`api/books/456/orders`
`api/orders`

Comment: (1) If request model means the format /structure request body payload in your terminology , yes . (2). I am not RESTifarians , but i would say they are pretty much common URL design based on many public REST APIs that I saw

Answer (score 2):

> Let's assume that I have the following resources.

Your "resources" look suspiciously like "tables".  Resources are closer to (logical) documents about information.

> what will be the most suitable URL and a request model for an endpoint that will create orders

For the most part, it doesn't matter what URL you use to create orders.  In a hypermedia application (think HTML), I'm going to submit a "form", and the meta data associated with that form are going to describe for the client how to compose a request from the form data.

So the human, or the code, that is manipulating the form doesn't need to know anything about the URL (when is the last time that you looked to see where Google was actually sending your search?)

As far as general purpose web components are concerned, the URL/URI is just an opaque identifier - they don't care what the spelling *means*.

A thing they do care about is whether the spelling is *the same as* something that they have cached.  One of the consequences of a successful `POST /x` message is that the cached representation(s) of `/x` are invalidated.

So if you like, you can think about which cached document should be refreshed when an order is created, and send the request to the identifier for that document.

> Should request models look like our resources or not?

It's not necessary.  Again, think about the web -- what would the representation of create order look like if you were POSTing form data?

```
clientId=1&bookId=2
```

or maybe

```
bookId=2&copies=3
```

If the "who is creating an order" is answered using the authorization headers.

In our HTTP requests and responses, we are fundamentally sending message representations - sequences of bytes that conform to some schema.  There's no particular reason that those sequences of bytes must, or must not, be the same as those we use elsewhere in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not REST, it is CRUD over HTTP. REST does not care about your URI structures and resources are very far from database tables. If CRUD is all you need, then download a CRUD generator library https://github.com/search?q=crud+generator&type=Repositories, which will generate all the upper and you won't need to write it manually.